# Can I paste from the X clipboard without middle clicking?

Tags: firefox, xorg

Is it possible to paste from the X clipboard without using the middle button?

My question refers to Firefox. I know it uses the gtk clipboard but it's still possible to paste from X with a middle click, so I thought about a possibility to do this with the keyboard too.

Are there any keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

There are two "clipboards" (see http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt )

If you want to use the keyboard an option is to just use the real clipboard instead of the goofy middle click / current selection easter egg. Then you can use ctrl+C, ctrl+V. (Or Shift+Insert)

I don't see a key shortcut for pasting the selection in the GTK+ source code, for what it's worth, so if you do want to avoid the Ctrl+C I don't see a way to do so.

Come to think of it, perhaps it could never work, because when you left-click into the entry to paste into it, or tab navigate into it, it's going to be auto-selected, which will blow away whatever you had selected before. Middle click is the only way to paste without changing the selection first.